# how to log full output of exim pipe command

Tags: python, log-files, exim

i need to debug a python script which is used in the exim transport pipe command.
i already tried `log_output` but it logs only first line of the output returned by the python script  which is a `traceback` error.

```
my_transport:
driver = pipe
command = /usr/bin/python /path/to/myscript.py
log_fail_output
group = mail
user = mail
```

i want to see full trackback error in `mainlog` in order to debug it.
how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [return_output](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_18.html#SEC532) directive

> return_output (pipe)
>
> Type: boolean
> Default: false
>
> If this option is true, and the command produced any output, the delivery is deemed to have failed whatever the return code from the command, and the output is returned in the delivery error message. Otherwise, the output is just discarded. However, if the message has a null sender (that is, it is a delivery error message), output from the command is always discarded, whatever the setting of this option.

Comment: i was looking for output to be logged in logfile. but i got  command output in the bounce mail(undelivered mail returned to sender).its enough.thankyou

Answer (score 0):

To add to @user9517's answer with the [return_output directive](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_18.html#SEC532), I'd like to share how I saw Exim log output on a RedHat based cPanel server:

1. Turn off any monitoring or service restarts of Exim.  E.g. cPanel servers have a 'Service Manager' that can stop restarts that would interfere with your debug run, as well as stop the service gracefully when you need to in a following step.
2. Check how Exim normally runs for you:

```
ps aux | grep "exi[m]"
```

3. Kill Exim, your command may be different from mine. (-9 is dangerous, know what you're doing)

```
kill -9 $( ps aux | grep "sbin\/exi[m]" )
```

4. Start Exim in debug mode with `-d`, and save output to a file as well as STDIN if desired, your command may be different from mine.  [+all](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-log_files.html#SECTlogselector) adds as much as possible AFAIK.

```
/usr/sbin/exim -d+all -ps -bd -q15m -oP /var/spool/exim/exim-daemon.pid 2&1 | tee ~/exim-debug.log
```

5. See Exim's routing.  This is just a handy one-liner to only show the successful routes taken.

```
cat ~/exim-debug.log | perl -0076 -ne '@x = $_ =~ /(^ ([^ ]*) .+? routed by \2 )/gs; $"="\n==========\n\n"; $cnt=0; for (@x){ print " -------->$_\n\n" unless $cnt % 2; $cnt++}'
```

The full log is where it mentions the child process.

```
grep -A15 'direct command' ~/exim-debug.log
```

The Exim mainlog also shows the result:

```
/var/log/exim_mainlog
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to log full output using the `use_shell` option. As it passes the whole command `/bin/sh`, this makes it possible to use shell redirects and pipes. Please note that the documentation deems this method less secure.

Your transport then becomes:

```
my_transport:
driver = pipe
command = /usr/bin/python /path/to/myscript.py 2>/tmp/debug_stderr.txt >/tmp/debug_stdout.txt
log_fail_output
group = mail
user = mail
use_shell = true
```

See documentation [here](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_pipe_transport.html).