# Alternative ways of sending full contents of incoming email to external script in Exim?

Tags: exim

For some strange reason, using the `pipe` command does not work as expected for me in Exim, and neither Google [nor ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/813509/how-to-execute-an-external-script-via-pipe-command-from-an-exim-system-filter) has been able to provide a solution for this problem so far. :-(

I'm therefore switching over to searching for an alternative solution (a.k.a. workaround) instead, more specifically not explicitly using the `pipe` command at all, which makes me seek the answer to the following new question instead:

**How can I, using any available config method in Exim, make sure that incoming emails (including their complete contents such as headers, body etc) are sent to an external script on the same server (in my case, a Python script), in a similar fashion to what the `pipe` command is supposed to do, but not using the `pipe` command explicitly as I do in [my other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/813509/how-to-execute-an-external-script-via-pipe-command-from-an-exim-system-filter)?**

My own primary suggestion so far is that I could configure a dedicated transport for this, similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/574909/how-to-log-full-output-of-exim-pipe-command), and then just make it so that all incoming emails are routed through this transport? My problem is just that I currently don't know how to accomplish the "*make it so that all incoming emails are routed through this transport*" part, so any solutions to this simple sub question might actually also be a valid reply to this entire question(!).

Also, [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/299349/exim-how-to-deliver-locally-and-send-a-copy-to-another-server) is seemingly using something called a "smarthost" to redirect (copies of) incoming email to a certain transport, but I'm still lacking both a sufficient understanding and the complete config directives to make practical use of it, but a possible answer might use this too perhaps?

(and please include real Exim config file input in your reply, and assume I have no previous knowledge of neither any particular Exim nor SMTP terminology)

Comment: You seem awfully sure of what you *don't* want... that makes it hard to give you an answer!

Comment: @WouterVerhelst Possibly hard to give an answer to the wrong/irrelevant question perhaps, but otherwise I really don't see why it would be a drawback to be specific with one's question? Specificity of the questions are rather normally encouraged at Stack Overflow... Very unconstructive and moronic to give a question minuspoints just because it is "too" well-defined and specific - that's rather vote abuse and should be reported...

Answer (score 0):

A smarthost handles ALL the mail for a MTA and is not relevant to the problem you are trying to solve.

I've setup such systems as you describe several times in the past, and the most robust and effective solution is to handle the extended requirement in the MDA not the MTA - and [procmail](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue14/procmail.html) provides sophisticated capabilities for implementing a range of behaviours - e.g. copy to both a mailbox and receiving script, differentially routing mail based on subject, recipient or sender (including the useful MAILER macro).

> I have no previous knowledge of neither any particular Exim nor SMTP terminology

erk, all the more reason you shouldn't mess with your MTA.